# How to migrate a particular state of a workitems ( i.e Only active state of workitems) under the VstsSyncMigrator Tool

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools, vsts-sync-migrator

I am using the tool version of V11.9.20. I have successfully migrated all workitems on one of my production move.

Now the requirement is there need to move only the active workitems. For that I have configured the below json fie. But result is showing me Active state along with proposed and resolved state.

Could you please help me out if I need to migrate only one state  or multiple state. Please advice.

I have configured as follows on my json file.

```
{
  "$type": "FieldValueMapConfig",
  "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
  "sourceField": "System.State",
  "targetField": "System.State",
  //"defaultValue": "New",
  "valueMapping": {
    //"Approved": "New",
    //"New": "New",
    "Active": "Active"
    //"In Progress": "In Progress",
    //"To Do": "New",
    //"Done": "Closed",
    //"Removed": "Removed"
 }
```

Thank you!
-Asit

Answer (score 1):

The value mapping feature does not filter the work item list, it allows you to mat one state to another state.

You should add `[System.State] = 'Active'` to the query.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Sorry for the late response. I will have a check and update on the same.

Comment: worked as expected. thank you!.

Comment: Thank you Martin. This can be close now.